# stopping a timeout in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, settimeout

Is there a way I can kill/(get rid of) a timeout in reactjs?

```
setTimeout(function() {
//do something
}.bind(this), 3000);
```

Upon some sort of click or action, I want to be able to completely stop and end the timeout. Is there a way to do this? thanks.

Comment: it's still just JS, you do it the same way you'd do it without React.

Comment: `clearTimeout` will work assuming you store the timer id.

Comment: [clear all timeouts](https://gist.github.com/yairEO/9c7513d99b41c561b004ac296eb4569a) can help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use mixins:

```
// file: mixins/settimeout.js:

var SetTimeoutMixin = {
    componentWillMount: function() {
        this.timeouts = [];
    },
    setTimeout: function() {
        this.timeouts.push(setTimeout.apply(null, arguments));
    },

    clearTimeouts: function() {
        this.timeouts.forEach(clearTimeout);
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        this.clearTimeouts();
    }
};

export default SetTimeoutMixin;
```

...and in your component:

```
// sampleComponent.js:
import SetTimeoutMixin from 'mixins/settimeout'; 

var SampleComponent = React.createClass({

    //mixins:
    mixins: [SetTimeoutMixin],

    // sample usage
    componentWillReceiveProps: function(newProps) {
        if (newProps.myValue != this.props.myValue) {
            this.clearTimeouts();
            this.setTimeout(function(){ console.log('do something'); }, 2000);
        }
    },
}

export default SampleComponent;
```

More info: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html

Comment: How would this translate to React using ES6 classes? Mixins are being deprecated soon.

Comment: For anyone wondering the same thing as @Scotty, I've submitted a 2017 version of the answer just below.

Comment: this is no longer up to date.

Answer (score 30):

Assuming this is happening inside a component, store the timeout id so it can be cancelled later. Otherwise, you'll need to store the id somewhere else it can be accessed from later, like an external store object.

```
this.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
  // Do something
  this.timeout = null
}.bind(this), 3000)

// ...elsewhere...

if (this.timeout) {
  clearTimeout(this.timeout)
  this.timeout = null
}
```

You'll probably also want to make sure any pending timeout gets cancelled in `componentWillUnmount()` too:

```
componentWillUnmount: function() {
  if (this.timeout) {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout)
  }
}
```

If you have some UI which depends on whether or not a timeout is pending, you'll want to store the id in the appropriate component's state instead.

Comment: There is a syntax error in the first code snippet, should be - `setTimeout(function() {` instead of `setTimeout(function(), {`

Comment: Do you need to set `this.timeout = null` in `componentWillUnmount()` after clearing it?  Seems tidiest?

Comment: there is error in }.bind(this),,  and this is an old syntax: componentWillUnmount: function() {

Comment: I've always wondered why people store some things in `this` (the component instance) and not in state. Because by that logic, why don't we store everything in `this`? Should I only store things that affect render in state, and the rest in `this`? If I wanted to store a count of ongoing parallel requests and only clear timeout when they're all completed, should I store that number in `this` as well? Does that have any downsides?

Answer (score 13):

Since React mixins are now deprecated, here's an example of a higher order component that wraps another component to give the same functionality as described in the accepted answer. It neatly cleans up any remaining timeouts on unmount, and gives the child component an API to manage this via props.

This uses ES6 classes and [component composition](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) which is the recommended way to replace mixins in 2017.

**In Timeout.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const Timeout = Composition => class _Timeout extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount () {
      this.timeouts = [];
    }

    setTimeout () {
      this.timeouts.push(setTimeout.apply(null, arguments));
    }

    clearTimeouts () {
      this.timeouts.forEach(clearTimeout);
    }

    componentWillUnmount () {
      this.clearTimeouts();
    }

    render () {
      const { timeouts, setTimeout, clearTimeouts } = this;

      return <Composition 
        timeouts={timeouts} 
        setTimeout={setTimeout} 
        clearTimeouts={clearTimeouts} 
        { ...this.props } />
    }
}

export default Timeout;
```

**In MyComponent.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Timeout from './Timeout';    

class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    // You can access methods of Timeout as they
    // were passed down as props.
    this.props.setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Hey! I'm timing out!")
    }, 1000)
  }

  render () {
    return <span>Hello, world!</span>
  }
}

// Pass your component to Timeout to create the magic.
export default Timeout(MyComponent);
```

Comment: Wicked! Cheers @jmgem!

Comment: This is great! How would you pass MyComponent to Timeout if you are using redux's `connect` function?

Comment: Why do you have to go through all this?  What is wrong with the answer of Jonny Buchannan?

Comment: does not work if i want to update a local state :        this.props.setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState( {clicked: false});
        }, 2000);

Comment: Thank you for this revision!

Answer (score 2):

I stopped a setTimeout in my react app with Javascript only:

(my use case was to auto-save only after a clear 3 seconds of no keystrokes)

```
timeout;

handleUpdate(input:any) {
    this.setState({ title: input.value }, () => {

        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
        this.timeout = setTimeout(() => this.saveChanges(), 3000);

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**2023**
Tested and working in production. This is the way I did it after this thread didn't provide me with an answer.

```
const MyComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({
  children,
  className = '',
}) => { 
  const timeoutRef = useRef<NodeJS.Timeout | null>(null)
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(
      () => setLoaded(true),
      10000
    )
    return () => {
      timeoutRef.current && clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current)
    }
    
  }, []) //eslint-disable-line

  const handleCancelTimeout = () => {
    timeoutRef.current && clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current)
  }

  return (
    <div>...</div>
  )
}
```