# how can I stop a function from calling itself? (React)

Tags: reactjs, function, state

I have an automation function which is kind of like pagination which keeps pushing data into a DB when it's pressed and it works how I want it, the only problem I have, its that it just can't be stopped, I tried putting if statements wherever it seemed logical but I can't get it to stop.
I am setting the `automate` push in a `timeout` because if not, it does an infinite loop and tries to push all items super fast.

```
function automatePush() {
    if (stop === true) return console.log("stoppped");
    setMutationState(true); // this is what allowes the products to be pushed
    setSliceStart((prev) => prev + 5); //pagination start
    setSliceEnd((prev) => prev + 5); //pagination end
    if (stop === false){ // if stop is not true then keep calling the function 
      setTimeout(() => {
        setMutationState(false); // this just refreshes the item to keep pushing the next ones
        automatePush(); // this calls itself to keep looping through items.
      }, 6000);
    }
  }
```

if I change my `stop` state to true manually before doing the `automate` and then I click `automate` it does console log the `'stoppped'` and the automation does not happen, as its what I want

this is how I am trying to stop it when the automation is going on

```
        <div>
          <p>
            by clicking "Automate" you can create all the products from the
            database (not including the ones you just created)
          </p>
          <button onClick={() => automatePush()}>Automate</button>  // this is the one that calls the automate
          <button onClick={() => setStop(true)}>STOP</button> // this one is the one that should stop it
        </div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do exactly here, but if the varible "stop" is not changing, this is expected behaviour. There is nothing to stop the recursion

Comment: That said, it's probably that `stop` is captured by the closure, and it's not mutate inside the closure itself so it never gets the updated value. You could use a ref that's mutable instead of state.

Comment: Use the timeout id to cancel it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29526739/stopping-a-timeout-in-reactjs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Countdown Timer unable to make a stop function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61599267/react-countdown-timer-unable-to-make-a-stop-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the `automatePush` is using the same `closure` every time that the initial `automatePush` has and the value of `stop` does not change in that closure.

Use the `ref` instead of `state` to hold the `stop` value. See the example below. I've modified your code to make it work.

```
const stop = useRef(true);

function automatePush() {
  if (stop.current) return console.log("stoppped");
  setMutationState(true);
  setSliceStart((prev) => prev + 5);
  setSliceEnd((prev) => prev + 5);
  setTimeout(() => {
    setMutationState(false);
    automatePush();
  }, 6000);
}
```

```
<div>
  <p>
    by clicking "Automate" you can create all the products from the database (not including the ones you just created)
  </p>
  <button 
    onClick={() => {
      stop.current = false;
      automatePush();
    }
  >Automate</button> 
  <button onClick={() => stop.current = true}>STOP</button>
</div>
```

~Prayag

Comment: Using the timeout id instead of a boolean would be best. But this way, it works with React.

Comment: @SirXtC  I am glad that it was useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to clear timeout (`stopPushing`) in your `useEffect` return function.

```
const [timeoutId, setTimeoutId] = useState(null)

const automatePush = () => {
  setMutationState(true)
  setSliceStart((prev) => prev + 5)
  setSliceEnd((prev) => prev + 5)
  const id = setTimeout(() => {
    setMutationState(false)
    automatePush()
  }, 6000)
  setTimeoutId(id)
}

const stopPushing = () => clearTimeout(timeoutId)

useEffect(() => {
  return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId)
}, [])
```

```html
<div>
   <button onClick={() => automatePush()}>Automate</button>
   <button onClick={() => stopPushing()}>STOP</button>
</div>
```